# How could I separate half of the values from one variable into two variables?

Tags: r

I have got a data list from a txt file, which has one variable. How could I put the second half values into Variable 2?

here's some of the data

4
0
0
0
3
2
0
0
6
7
6
2
1
11
6
1
2
1
1
2
0
2
2
1
0
12
8
4
5
0
5
4
1
0
8
2
5
10
17
1

I don't know why it's look like this but it was a single column in the txt file.

Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a vector, you can use vector operations with `length`

```
> x <- seq(1:20)  # twenty values

> x[1:(length(x)/2)]  # first ten values
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> x[-(1:(length(x)/2))]  # second ten values
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Or if you're starting with a `data.frame` and want to make two columns from one, use `nrow` instead of `length`

```
> x <- data.frame(var1 = seq(1:20))
> y <- data.frame(var1 = x[1:(nrow(x)/2), ], var2 = x[-(1:(nrow(x)/2)), ])
> y
##    var1 var2
## 1     1   11
## 2     2   12
## 3     3   13
## 4     4   14
## 5     5   15
## 6     6   16
## 7     7   17
## 8     8   18
## 9     9   19
## 10   10   20
```

Comment: I should ask from the beginning, I started with this
> x <- read.table ("list.txt", header=T, sep=",")
then I follow your way to do
but it came out with the whole list appear

Comment: Then could you post some of the data in your original post, please?  It's not quite clear how the data looks to begin with.

Comment: That was what I want, great thanks. one last thing, what should I do if I would like to use the commend "tapply(variable1,variable2,mean)" to find out the mean, coz it came out with "Error in tapply(variable1, variable2, mean) : 
  object 'variable2' not found"

Comment: Use the function `rowMeans` instead. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: nono I mean the mean for var1 and the mean for var2

Comment: Ahh, then it's simply `sapply(y, mean)` (using the variables I used above).

Comment: thanks alot it's all done. R is quite interesting, just started using it yesterday, it's really helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` for example :

```
xx <- 1:10
split(1:10,rep(c('a','b'),each=length(xx)/2))
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or better using `split` and `cut`:

```
 split(xx,cut(xx,2,label=c('a','b')))
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I got something like

$`1`
[1] 1 3 5 7 9

$`2`
[1]  2 4 6 8 10